# how to rank using count function in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data like below:

[image]

Now I am trying to find the max 3 earners from each `department`. For that, I am trying to resolve my inner query where I am trying to use `count(*)` for **`ranking`** but somehow it's not working as expected.

```
select Employee.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee E WHERE id = E.id AND Salary  E.Salary) as employees_who_earn_more from Employee
```

`Output`:

```
+---+-----+------+------------+------+
| id| name|salary|departmentId|rownum|
+---+-----+------+------------+------+
|  1|  Joe| 60000|           1|     0|
|  2|Ralph| 30000|           1|     0|
|  3| Joel| 50000|           1|     0|
|  4|Tracy| 55000|           1|     0|
+---+-----+------+------------+------+
```

`Expected`:

```
+---+-----+------+------------+------+
| id| name|salary|departmentId|rownum|
+---+-----+------+------------+------+
|  1|  Joe| 60000|           1|     0|
|  2|Ralph| 30000|           1|     3|
|  3| Joel| 50000|           1|     2|
|  4|Tracy| 55000|           1|     1|
+---+-----+------+------------+------+
```

**`NOTE`**: I don't want to use any `windowing` functions over here and I do want to consider cases where employees can have the same salary.

Comment: Your query has syntax errors and shouldn't compile. If you want a row number, why not use `row_number()`?

Comment: I have added a `note` at the end of the post

Comment: this question looks similar to what you want, btw - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using below query:

```
select *, (
    select Count(distinct salary) -1
    from employees e2 
    where e2.deptId= e.deptId 
      and (e2.salary > e.salary or (e2.salary = e.salary and e2.id <=e.id))
) rownum
from employees e;
```

This query works as a `dense_rank()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *correlated subquery* using *count*

```
select *, (
    select Count(*) -1
    from Employees e2 
    where e2.deptId= e.deptId 
      and (e2.salary > e.salary or (e2.salary = e.salary and e2.id = e.id))
) rownum
from Employees e;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7bb74402ec15c716b900fb50808e76fe)

Comment: This doesn't work when a person has the same salary. It should work kinda dense_rank()

Comment: Your sample data doesn't include this edge case - however perhaps you can amend the criteria to be `and e2.id = e.id`, that should yield equal counts I think.

Comment: See this slighty amended [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1794a04a7f1b3b49f3940a7a900405ea)

Comment: Again, if I want 4 max salaries then your code won't work.